# oneTimeSetUp with JMeter-JUnit sampler

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, junit4

I'm currently trying to create a test plan with `JMeter` 3.0 using JUnit sampler.

The problem I encounter is that `JMeter` opens one browser for each sampler I use.

Is there a way to define a `oneTimeSetUp` (`@BeforeClass`) in order to open a browser, execute my scenario (`@Test`) in it and close my browser with a `oneTimeTearDown` (`@AfterClass`)?